# Need help: NodeJs app deployed on Google Cloud Run , unable to connect to Google Cloud SQL Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have node Js code below which connects to PostgreSql db using connection pool:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  database: "",
  password: "",
  port: 5432,
});

app.get("/get_que", (req, res) => {
  pool.query(
    "SELECT json FROM surveys where available = TRUE;",
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      res.json({ data: results.rows });
    }
  );
});
```

Above app is deployed in Google Cloud Run and configured Google Cloud SQL (PostgresSql connection), but unable to connect from Google Cloud Run app.

Using Cloud SQL proxy in local, I am able to connect to cloud sql instance.

I tried public ip of the Cloud SQL instance in the "host" parameter in the above app, it is not connecting,

How to connect to Google Cloud SQL instance from the above NodeJs app which is deployed on Google Cloud Run?.

Comment: You need to enable to public IP of the Cloud SQL and setup a connection via the Cloud Run connections tab. Also after that you need to connect using unixsockets /cloudsql/<instance_id>

Comment: I have attached Cloud SQL instance to cloud run while deploying the revision. Now, in my code , in the host parameter i need to put '\cloudsql\<instance_id>'?

Comment: const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

//Below is for Google cloud
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: '/cloudsql/<instance connection name>/.s.PGSQL.5432',
  database: 'db1',
  password: 'password123'
  //port: 5432,
});  tried above host parameter , also added 'SQL Client' role to service account. still not working

Answer (score 2):

Even though the public IP is enabled in the Cloud SQL instance **by default** no networks are allowed. [See the adding authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add).

You have a very detailed guide in [Connecting from Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default).

Comment: how to find ip address to add in the authorized networks?. my app which is deployed in cloud run need to connect to Cloud Sql instance. I have also added this SQL instance , while deploying the app to cloud run.

Comment: If you use the Cloud SQL connection name with Unix sockets you do not need to add the network.

Comment: If you want to use the public id, you need to add the public IP of your cloud run service. (Usually you can directly select as it is autocompleted Authorized Neworks)

Comment: thank you. i removed /.s.PGSQL.5432 it is working fine . Cloud run automatically add this  value at run time. so need to suffix the above value again